# XNA convert mouse position to 3d co-ordinates

Tags: c#, xna

I have drawn a 3D grid using an array and want to be able to select an individual tile with the mouse but can't seem to get the 3D position correctly.
I am drawing each square of the grid out of 2 triangles, starting at 0,0,0 but when placing the cursor on the bottom left corner I get data like X 0.823, Y 0.676
The code I am using for mouse coordinates is as follows

```
        MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();

        Vector3 nearScreenPoint = new Vector3(ms.X, ms.Y, 0f);
        Vector3 farScreenPoint = new Vector3(ms.X, ms.Y, 1f);
        Vector3 nearWorldPoint = device.Viewport.Unproject(nearScreenPoint, projection, view, world);
        Vector3 farWorldPoint = device.Viewport.Unproject(farScreenPoint, projection, view, world);

        Vector3 direction = farWorldPoint - nearWorldPoint;
        direction.Normalize();

        Ray r = new Ray(nearWorldPoint, direction);

        Plane p = new Plane(0, 1, 0, 0f);

        // calculate distance of intersection point from r.origin
        float denominator = Vector3.Dot(p.Normal, r.Direction);
        float numerator = Vector3.Dot(p.Normal, r.Position) + p.D;
        float t = -(numerator / denominator);

        Vector3 pickedPosition = nearWorldPoint + direction * t;

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "" + fps + "    " + pickedPosition.X + "    -    " + pickedPosition.Z, new Vector2(100, 100), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.End();
```

Code for drawing a single square on the grid

```
        Matrix projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
        Matrix world = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(xPos, yPos, zHeight), new Vector3(xPos, yPos + zRotation, 0), new Vector3(0, 5, 0));


        foreach (EffectPass pass in grassEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();

            VertexPositionTexture[] vertices = createCubeTexture(0, 0, 1, 0f);
            device.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, vertices, 0, 2, VertexPositionTexture.VertexDeclaration);
        }
```

And finally the square creation code

```
    private VertexPositionTexture[] createCubeTexture(float xlocation, float ylocation, float size, float zlocation)
    {
        VertexPositionTexture[] vertices;

        vertices = new VertexPositionTexture[6];

        vertices[0].Position = new Vector3(xlocation - size, ylocation - size, zlocation);
        vertices[0].TextureCoordinate.X = 0;
        vertices[0].TextureCoordinate.Y = 1;
        vertices[1].Position = new Vector3(xlocation - size, ylocation + size, zlocation);
        vertices[1].TextureCoordinate.X = 0;
        vertices[1].TextureCoordinate.Y = 0;
        vertices[2].Position = new Vector3(xlocation + size, ylocation - size, zlocation);
        vertices[2].TextureCoordinate.X = 1;
        vertices[2].TextureCoordinate.Y = 1;
        vertices[3].Position = new Vector3(xlocation - size, ylocation + size, zlocation);
        vertices[3].TextureCoordinate.X = 0;
        vertices[3].TextureCoordinate.Y = 0;
        vertices[4].Position = new Vector3(xlocation + size, ylocation + size, zlocation);
        vertices[4].TextureCoordinate.X = 1;
        vertices[4].TextureCoordinate.Y = 0;
        vertices[5].Position = new Vector3(xlocation + size, ylocation - size, zlocation);
        vertices[5].TextureCoordinate.X = 1;
        vertices[5].TextureCoordinate.Y = 1;

        return vertices;
    }
```

Comment: You specified the wrong plane normal. It should probably be a constant, not something that depends on the mouse position. Or does your plane move?

Comment: How should I normalize it? They can change the rotation and move around but the grid stays flat where it is. I'm very new to 3d stuff in case you cant tell :P Trying to convert a 2D game, proving more difficult than I thought

Comment: If the grid is always flat on the x-z plane, then use a normal of `(0, 1, 0)`.

Comment: I have tried that and I get just as seemingly random numbers... They never seem to correlate with where I have draw the squares atall

Comment: Can you update the code and post some sample values? The y-component should always be 0.

Comment: Updated above, think that's everything needed...

Comment: Your grid is on the xy-plane. Use a plane normal of `(0, 0, 1)`.

Comment: Knew it would be something simple! thanks a lot. Is this not the recommended way to do it or does it not make much difference?

Comment: No, it's ok. But you shouldn't create the vertices every frame. Create them once in a vertex buffer and use this to render.